# How to estimate this variable in an MILP formulation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, logistic-regression, linear-programming

This is my first question being asked here. I've thought about different methods to do it, but to no avail. I want to estimate a variable that is either 0 or a positive number. Then I want to use this estimation in a mixed integer linear programming (MILP) formulation. I have a big dataset with proper features that are labeled properly (the label is either 0 or a positive number). I'm thinking of using a machine learning approach to estimate this variable. It's important that the estimation is 0 (not a small number) when the label is 0. I was thinking of using a binary classification first (to divide zero and non-zero labels), and then a regression to estimate the positive numbers. But I'm not sure that I'll be able to model that in a MILP formulation efficiently. Any ideas? Can I use neural networks for this purpose?

I hope that I've been able to describe the problem well enough.

Comment: For MILP you might get better responses over at the [OR stack](https://or.stackexchange.com/).  For something else, start with [zero-inflated regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model).

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben! Zero-inflated regression seems like an interesting solution. I will look into it.